# ClickHouse returns AMBIGUOUS_COLUMN_NAME error

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Is this a ClickHouse bug? How come I get the AMBIGUOUS_COLUMN_NAME error for such query:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    `time` DateTime
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
ORDER BY time
```

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        toUInt64(time) AS time,
        toHour(test.time)
    FROM test
)
ORDER BY time ASC
```

Received exception from server (version 22.6.1):
Code: 352. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: Block structure mismatch in (columns with identical name must have identical structure) stream: different types:
time DateTime UInt32(size = 0)
time UInt64 UInt64(size = 0). (AMBIGUOUS_COLUMN_NAME)

It does not work with "WITH" either:

```
WITH subquery AS (
    SELECT
        toUInt64(time) AS time,
        toHour(test.time)
    FROM test
)
SELECT *
FROM subquery
ORDER BY subquery.time ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        toUInt64(time) AS time,
        toHour(test.time)
    FROM test
)
ORDER BY time ASC
```

which amounts to `SELECT time, toHour FROM ...`

The ORDER BY wants to know whether you mean the inner or outer `time`.

So define a table alias (A or B) for each relation,
and explicitly refer to either `A.time` or `B.time`.
Now it's not ambiguous.

Comment: I tried using WITH but same error. See my last SQL.

Comment: But if I add one more order by it starts working- which is even strange. 
WITH subquery AS
    (
        SELECT
            toUInt64(time) AS time,
            toHour(test.time) AS hour
        FROM test
    )
SELECT *
FROM subquery
ORDER BY
    subquery.time ASC,
    hour ASC